# Microsoft Table Structure Recognition Transformer

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I have been working on table structure recognition problem, I am using Pre-treined Detecction Transformer trained on PubTables-1M dataset by Microsoft. I have fine-tuned the model on Fintabnet to align it with financial table layouts. However, it's not giving me good results specifically it's not able to localize the rows well, e.g the rows towards the center of the page are pretty bad. It's detecting the rows at the top and bottom of the image pretty well.
The model architecture is resnet18 backbone, and transformer encoder and decoder. I have plotted the intermediate layers in backbone in an attempt to diganose the issue, however I have been able to understand the reason.
[image: These images are showing the results after NMS, otherwise the there are false positives in the center and there is a clutter of rows]

Any tip or leads to make it better?

Comment: Add your fine tuning code, will have to go through  it to understand how it can be fixed.